# Find a string of highlighted text with a nonhighlighted white space interrupting somewhere inside the otherwise highlighted string

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, find

I would like to find (in Microsoft Word 10) a string that consists of some (highlighted text), a (non-highlighted white space), followed by some (highlighted text).  Any ideas?

Comment: This could be done with Regex, But the highlighting thing. Not sure... Maybe with a VBScript.

Comment: The advanced find dialogue, at the end of the home tab under find, allows you to search using wildcards and formatting such as highlight. However it doesn't match the white space as it only lets you find whole highlighted terms.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in a multi-step process.  The first stage is to find and replace all non-highlighted spaces with highlighted spaces which ALSO have a unique formatting feature (for removal again later) eg red bold italics so that you have highlighted strings (ie no non-highlighted space in between).

Then you can do your second find to find the text you are looking for (with highlight format option selected).

Then a final find and replace to replace all the specially formatted spaces to remove the formatting (eg red bold italics) and highlighting you applied to the spaces.